# Unable to write ndef record after particular length

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am having problems when writing using ndef record because if it exceeds a particular length it does not write.
//My data is of the form :

```
// String NFCPayload = sb.append("TEST").append(":").append("test@test.com").append(":").append("1").append(":").append("2").append(":").append("5").toString();
```

It works, but now if even a single alphabet is added it does not.

```
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException 
{
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}


private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
{
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}
```

Comment: What tag are you using? Are you sure that the data fits into the tag memory?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Thank you for the feedback. I am using Mifare Classic 1k. if i write only one string of length less than 36 characters i can easily read and write. But i think the problem is with sectors and block and being an amateur i guess i don't know what to do. Kindly, if you can please give an example of  using all 4 sectors of a block for writing and reading as well i would be grateful to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a new card or was it used for something else before? Are all sectors accessible with the factory keys (or NDEF keys)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland new card and i have used mifare app and have checked that all sectors are accessible but i came to realize that sector 0 is read only. so, could you please provide a sample code for writing in all four blocks of sector 1. It would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If sector 0 is read-only, then that's most likely the problem. Sector 0 is needed in order to allocate memory (i.e. sectors) to the NDEF message. There is no way to use the NDEF abstraction layer without that. Regarding the use of block 3 (i.e. the last block of each sector): that block contains metadata for access control (keys and access bits). You can't use that block for regular data (at least most of it).

Comment: @MichaelRoland Understood. But can you please provide some sample code for other sectors.